# Wrong answer for lyap() function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm getting a weird answer from matlab using the lyap() function for generating a stable controller
my code is

```
m=1;c=2;k=1;
A=[0 1;-k/m -c/m]
B=[0 1/m]'
C=[1 0;0 1];
D=[0 0]';
u=2;
Q=eye(2);
ro=60;
k=0.99*ro;
P=lyap(A,Q)
```

What I'm getting is

```
P =

    1.5000   -0.5000
   -0.5000    0.5000
```

which is giving me an unstable controller,
while when solving it alone I get

```
 p1 =

    1.5000    0.5000
    0.5000    0.5000
```

which is a stable controller.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think your solution p1 is wrong, substituting p1 into the Lyapunov matrix eqn: `A*P + P*A' + Q` does not result in the zero matrix

Comment: so is their a lyap function for this equation?

Comment: ok conditions are violated, the eigenvalues add to zero, thus there is not a unique solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [Mathworks Documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/lyap.html)

Limitations:

The continuous Lyapunov equation has a unique solution if the eigenvalues a1,a2,...,an of A and b1,b2,...,bn of B satisfy

ai+bj ~= 0 for all i,j

and from your values

```
eig(A)
    ans =
    -1
    -1
eig(Q)
ans =
     1
     1
```

we can see these add to zero, thus there is not unique solution for these inputs

However I have no idea why the error message isn't generated, possibly time to report a bug

Comment: This can also be confirmed by taking `eig(P)` and `eig(p1)`, which gives the same result.